react query invalidadeQueries with strange behavior onSuccess
I'm fighting here to understand react query and this part is really annoying...
When i put the code like this it works normally:
  const { mutate: deleteUser, isPending } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => customFetch.delete("/" + user.id),
    onSuccess: queryClient.invalidateQueries(),
  });


Where i kinda send the queryClient.invalidateQueries() as the value of the "onSuccess", well at least this is what i understood of this react query confusing docs.
But when i put the code like this one below, i have to click twice into the button that triggers this "deleteUser" function in order to work, or i click twice the button or i refresh the page, then it really does the "delete" request.
  const { mutate: deleteUser, isPending } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => customFetch.delete("/" + user.id),
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries();
    },
  });

And the strange thing is that when i go to another react component and use the code like this it works:
  const {
    mutate: createUser,
    isPending,
    error,
  } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => customFetch.post("/", { name, job, age }),
    onSuccess: () => {
      setName("");
      setAge("");
      setJob("");
      queryClient.invalidateQueries();
      toast.success("User added");
    },
    onError: () => {
      toast.error(error.response.data);
    },
  });


Why different behaviors with the same code? how to make code block 1 work without making the user refresh the page to see the query result?
